# How do I use negative numbers in a range in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, operators, negative-number

I have the following code:

```
switch self.score
        {
        case 1:
            self.score = self.score - 2
        case -10...-10000: // ! Expected expression after unary operator
            println("lowest score")
            self.score = -10
        default:
            self.score = self.score - 1
        }
```

I have also tried `case -1000...-10:`. Both get the same error `! Expected expression after unary operator`.

What I would really like to do is `case <= -10:`, but I can't figure out how to that without getting this error `Unary operator cannot be separated from its operand`.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Try wrapping in parentheses maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the context of a switch case, `a ... b` is a "closed interval" and the start
must be less or equal to the end of the interval. Also a plus or minus sign must be
separated from `...` by a space (or the number enclosed in parentheses), so both

```
case -10000...(-10):
case -10000 ... -10:
```

work.

`case <= -10:` can be written in Swift
using a "where clause":

```
case let x where x <= -10:
```

Starting with **Swift 4** this can be written as a “one-sided range expression”:

```
case ...(-10):
```

Comment: @webmagnets: In the "Where" section of the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html: *"A switch case can use a where clause to check for additional conditions ..."*